# How do I filter a polars DataFrame by verifying if the value of a column is contained by an vector?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I have a dataframe which has the column "ID" with data typed as UInt32 and I have a vector named ids. I want to return a dataframe with the rows which "ID" value is contained by the vector ids.

**MINIMAL WANTED EXAMPLE**

```rs
use polars::df;
use polars::prelude::*;

fn filter_by_id(table: &DataFrame, ids: Vec<u32>) -> DataFrame {
    df!{
        "ID" => &[1, 3, 5],
        "VALUE" => &["B", "D", "F"]
    }.unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let table = df!{
        "ID" => &[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "VALUE" => &["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
    }.unwrap();
    let ids = vec![1, 3, 5];
    let filtered_table = filter_by_id(&table, ids);
    println!("{:?}", table);
    println!("{:?}", filtered_table);
}
```

| ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | D |
| 4 | E |
| 5 | F |

filter vector = [1, 3, 5]

wanted output =

| ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | B |
| 3 | D |
| 5 | F |

Comment: Can you provide a sample DataFrame & id-vector, and the expected output? That would help to clarify the question, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

polars mostly operates on `Series` and `Expr` types. So by converting your vec to a `Series` you can accomplish this task relatively easy.

```rust
use polars::df;
use polars::prelude::*;

fn main () {
    let table = df!{
        "ID" => &[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "VALUE" => &["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
    }.unwrap();
    let ids = vec![1, 3, 5];
    // convert the vec to `Series`
    let ids_series = Series::new("ID", ids);
    // create a filter expression
    let filter_expr = col("ID").is_in(lit(ids_series));
    // filter the dataframe on the expression
    let filtered = table.lazy().filter(filter_expr).collect().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", filtered);
}
```

Note: you will need to add the features `lazy` and `is_in`

`cargo add polars --features lazy,is_in`

Comment: I'm new to rust and polars. Where I could find a list of these features in crate's documentation? I'm missing a lot of functions, and needing to rewrite this by hand and these functions may be already  implemented as features.

Comment: the rust docs have a list of available [opt-in features](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/#compile-times-and-opt-in-features)

Comment: is there any "not_in" equivalent?

Comment: there is a `not` method on expressions. This negates any previous boolean expression. so `.is_in(x).not()` would be the equivalent of `not_in`